# Bootstrap 4 - using <select> instead of tabs (<li>)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to change look of bootstrap tabs to have dropdown select instead of standard tabs made with `<ul>` and `<li>`

I have relatively small area (like col-3) where I need to display tabs with lot of tabs (like 7-10 tabs), but it looks ugly on small screens as it span to 3-4rows.

I would like to use select dropdown (maybe some jquery addons for slecet) where I would always use that dropdown to select tab.

It needs to be `<select>` as I want to show all the time selected tab (standard bootstrap dropdown, dont do it, it just offers options but not showing what is selected).

Comment: why not hide the `<ul>` and `<li>` and just link the `<select>` triggering those tabs?

Comment: Sorry, can you show some example, as I don't understand what exactly you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to hide `<ul>` and `<li>` and just trigger them by `<select>`

Here's an example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li hidden><a href="#" id="a1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li hidden><a href="#" id="a2">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li hidden><a href="#" id="a3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

<select onchange="selectTab(this.value)">
  <option value="1">Menu 1</option>
  <option value="2">Menu 2</option>
  <option value="3">Menu 3</option>
</select>
```

And example JavaScript:

```
    function selectTab(e){
      switch(e){
        case 1:
            $('#a1').click();
        break;
        case 2:
            $('#a2').click();
        break;
        case 3:
            $('#a3').click();
        break;
        default:

      }
    }
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/dfg65hpx/1/)'s the jsfiddle